# sorting rows in a file according to a number included in the rows

Tags: java

I have the following text file (offline.txt):

```
# Timestamp, X, Y, MAC Address of AP, RSS
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 28:c6:8e:85:80:d3 -71
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:a1 -75
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:a2 -74
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:b1 -84
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:b2 -85
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:b0 -85
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:a0 -74
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:87:04:41 -75
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:87:04:40 -73
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:87:04:42 -74
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:87:04:52 -96
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:87:04:50 -97
```

I would like to sort the lines of the file according to the number in the 5th column of the file in descending order if a value is repeated it doesn't matter the order of the repeated values.

For example this is the desired output (offline_out.txt) I want for the previous particular text file:

```
# Timestamp, X, Y, MAC Address of AP, RSS
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 28:c6:8e:85:80:d3 -71
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:87:04:40 -73
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:87:04:42 -74
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:a0 -74
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:a2 -74
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:a1 -75
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:b1 -84
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:b2 -85
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:b0 -85
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:87:04:52 -96
1395444273179 35.19967269897461 19.1965389251709 00:1a:1e:87:04:50 -97
```

I know how to read the file, and I know that the "sort" function in java can help me sorting.
So my idea is to extract all the numbers in the 5th row, save them in a vector then sort the vector and find a way to assiciate the numbers to the specific rows so once the number is sorted the rows are also sorted, and then save them to another file. any ideas on how to program this?

This is the program I have so far:

```
public class extract {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    File inputFile = new File("offline.txt");
    File tempFile = new File("offline_out.txt");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    //while to read all the lines, but how can I store only the numbers to a vector an associate them to a specific row?
        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           }
    }

    //to save the output file
    boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);

    }
```

Comment: I think you've got a good approach. Work out each step in your approach individually and you should arrive at your desired result. I suggest breaking out each step in your approach into its own method.

Comment: Maybe you could read each line into an object, then sort the list of objects using `Comparator` on the last column?

Comment: if I treat each line as an object, how cam I say to "comparator" that the lines should sort according to the number in the 5th column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `TreeMap` to store the lines corresponding to the last number in the particular line

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

    // split the line and use the last value as key
    if (!currentLine.contains("Timestamp"))
        map.put(Integer.parseInt(currentLine.split("\\s+")[4]), currentLine);
    else
        map.put(0, currentLine);
}
```

Finally you can print and see the results(or you can write this to a file as you please):

```
for(Integer key : map.descendingKeySet())
    System.out.println(map.get(key));
```

**The repeated lines are not being captured in the above, updating the structure to capture it**

Use the map with the `Arraylist`, to store the lines corresponding to the particular number

```
TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

    int key;
    if (!currentLine.contains("Timestamp"))
        // split the line and use the last value as key
        key = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.split("\\s+")[4];
    else
        key = 0;
    ArrayList<String> lines;
    if (!map.contains(key)) //if the key doesn't exist create a new arraylist
        lines = new ArrayList<String>();            
    else  // if the key exists use the arraylist in the map
        lines = map.get(key);
    lines.add(currentLine);
    map.put(key, lines);
}
```

and for printing:

```
for(Integer key : map.descendingKeySet())
    for(String line : map.get(key))
        System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: thank you it partially works, the problem is that it ignores repeated lines.

Comment: In the map, the keys will be unique and that's why the repeated lines will be ignored. Do you have any sorting preference in the case of repeated lines too??

Comment: thank you it seems to be working, but for some reason the output include brackets between the code, and the repeated lines are on the same line. any recommendations on how to fix this?

Comment: you keep asking just basic questions, check the updated answer for printing the lines

Answer (score 1):

Create a value object bean class having two fields, `number` and `line`. Implement `comparable` and override the `compareTo` method in that class. Populate an `ArrayList` of this bean class as you scan the file. Then sort the `ArrayList`.

Comment: Or as @shree.pat18 comments, use a `Comparator` if you think you will want to sort it by other values. However, I think `Comparable` will be fine here

Answer (score 0):

how about just using String.split

```
String [] arr = currentLine.split ("\\s+");
```

try using a treeMap for storage

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html